# how do i align contact form 7 next to text

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

i am working a WordPress contact page, and would like to have the a Google map and below it a section with the contact details (physical address, telephone, email etc) and to the right hand side of these contact details i would like to have the "contact form 7" form, and i would like help on how to align the contact form shortcode such that text is to the left hand side of the contact form. what i currently have is

```
    <p align="left">
     Please fill in the form on the right 
     or use the contact information below 
     to contact us.

    <strong>Tel:</strong> 310 0000 <strong>Fax: </strong>310 0000

    <strong>Physical Address</strong>
    lot 20697, Western northQ

    <strong>Postal Address</strong>
     PO Box 2842, Jersey

    </p>


    [contact-form-7 id="761" title="Contact form 1"]
```

and what that did is just display the contact form below the contact details, instead of on the right handside

and i also reduced the width of my contact form in my css so it can fit next to the text

```
    #contact-form { width: 250px; }
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of CSS and organization would work :)

## HTML

```
<div id="contact">
    <div id="left"> 

      <p>
         Please fill in the form on the right 
         or use the contact information below 
         to contact us.

        <strong>Tel:</strong> 310 0000 <strong>Fax: </strong>310 0000

        <strong>Physical Address</strong>
        lot 20697, Western northQ

        <strong>Postal Address</strong>
         PO Box 2842, Jersey

        </p>
    </div>

        <div id="right">[contact-form-7 id="761" title="Contact form 1"]</div></div>
```

## CSS

```
#contact{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#contact #left{
width: 40%;
float: left;
}

#contact #right{
width: 60%;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have a left and right float. They can both be left, just have the information first.

Comment: and do a clear:both; on the next block's style, such as <div style="width:99%; height:1px; clear:both;" ></div> keep your floats from running away.

Comment: For sure. Just a suggestion of how can solve this. Thanks for the collaboration.

Comment: I always do floats, to 99% some older versions of IE can have issues rounding the percents into px and wind up just over 100% which will drop your float to the next line